# Map Route 53 Domain to Lightsail Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, amazon-lightsail

I'm trying out hosting wordpress on aws, but i'm not able to connect my domain to the related instance. When i want to open my instance in the browser, the error says "Server not found" on firefox / "DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN" on chrome.

the setup:
Domain: w3alx.de registered on aws route 53
Instance:

- Wordpress Instance created with AWS Lightsail / default configuration
- Atached Static IP to the Instance: 3.78.31.183.
- Instance is up and running and accessible via the static IP

i tried severall configs according to route 53 hosting zones and name servers as well as dns configs directly in lightsail, but nothing seems to work. I googled a lot about changing name servers and so on but nothing did help.

Currently the domain is set up within a fresh hosted zone in route 53.
The name servers seem also proper configured to me, the domain and the hosted zone are poinitng to the same. i tested it via

```
whois
```

and

```
dig +trace
```

against the domain in the console and received the right nameservers and a record to the instance.
Weirdly i also included a CNAME record to catch [www.w3alx.de](http://www.w3alx.de) and point it to non www, but this record is not shown in the tests or testing tools like: [Google Toolbox](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#ANY/) or [DNS Checker](https://dnschecker.org/all-dns-records-of-domain.php)

i also tried to set it up via the lightsail dns service without the name servers>/hosting zone from route 53, but still got the exact same result. name servers looked perfectly good, but received the same errors when calling the domain in the browser...

Sorry, if this a silly beginner question, but i'm totally lost on thid one....

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `dig -t ns w3alx.de` returns AWS nameservers for me and I see the CNAME you say you don't see: `$ dig www.w3alx.de +short` -> `w3alx.de.
3.78.31.183`

Comment: @jordanm Thanks for cecking! yeah i don't know whats really going on here. i got the dig +trace command from a google search.

Comment: @jordanm Thanks for cecking! yeah i don't know whats really going on here. i got the dig +trace command from a google search. your commands gave me weird results e.g. the first one: ; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> -t ns w3alx.de
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 10371\... \And sorry for the bad commenting, should have learned markdown before i guess...

Comment: But at least shouldn't i get the same response containing the default wordpress page on w3alx.de as i get on 3.78.31.183 ? And if not, where is the error?^^

Comment: DNS servers cache responses. If you misconfigure DNS and NXDOMAIN is returned, that response will be remembered. Any changes you make will require the old value to expire before DNS resolvers will request the new value. The chain of DNS servers that your desktop uses to resolve DNS queries will be different than the chain my system uses. In other words, time is a significant variable when configuring and managing DNS.

Comment: @JohnHanley Thanks for your response and explanation. After a few days my DNS records work, although i didn't change anything. so it was really just a caching issue....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, in fact, in the end it was just a caching issue and after a few days the records work perfectly fine. Didn't know, that i receive a cached result in the browser, even though the dig command shows already the right records....